# SSL for sub domain without wildcard

Tags: security, ssl, https, wildcard-subdomain

I have a domain `www.example.com` , and I have an ssl for it.It is working fine.But I have unlimited subdomains,which comes as `user.example.com`

But even if I have ssl for example.com , the subdomains shows as if doesn't have ssl.I have searched online and found that there is something called wildcard ssl which is very costly.Is there some way  I could use my current ssl or possibly an normal ssl(not wildcard) for my sub-domains ?

I wanted it this way `https://user.example.com/`

Im pretty new to ssl and it seems the wildcard ssl are very costly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcard ssl can be used with multiple subdomains of a domain.So it's cost is high. I f you have multiple subdomains under a domain, you need to purchase a wildcard ssl.

Wildcard certificates secure the common name and all subdomains at the level you specify when you submit your request. Just add an asterisk (*) in the subdomain area to the left of the common name.

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work.

Ways to fix:

1. Buy an expensive wildcard certificate as you mentioned
2. Buy another SSL certificate for `user.example.com` **AND** purchase and setup an additional IP address from your provider - because you can only have one SSL host per IP address (the hostname request parameter is itself encrypted).

Comment: If I were rich enough to buy a wildcard cerificate I would do this :P thats why I asked if there where any work arounds